# How to reduce/concat objects based on some other value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am wondering what js functions can be used in the following case to get some array values together.

Here I want to concatenate the description values if the date value is null.

```
var incomes = [ { date: '05/03', description: '1st Description on 05/03', amount: '399.49' },
                { date: null, description: '1st Description continued on 05/03', amount: null },
                { date: null, description: '1st Description continued on 05/03', amount: null },
                { date: '05/03', description: '2nd Description on 05/03', amount: '269.85' },
                { date: null, description: '2nd Description continued on 05/03', amount: null },
                { date: null, description: '2nd Description continued on 05/03', amount: null }];
```

The result should look like this:

```
var results = [ { date: '05/03',
                  description: '1st Description on 05/03, 1st Description continued on 05/03, 1st Description continued on 05/03', 
                  amount: '399.49' },
                { date: '05/03', 
                  description: '2nd Description on 05/03, 2nd Description continued on 05/03, 2nd Description continued on 05/03', 
                  amount: '269.85' }];
```

I think that we can use the usual loops, conditions, etc. But are there any handy method to solve this?

Comment: So just to be clear, you're joining values together based on the _order_ in which they appear? When a non-null date is encountered, it represents the first item, and any subsequent descriptions should be joined to it until another date is encountered?

Comment: Here's how I personally would write https://jsfiddle.net/0e8xhp75/2/

Comment: @Engin: That approach is over-complex, and ends up modifying the input objects, which could be dangerous if they were being used for something else.

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't a good use case for reduce/concat types of operations. Reduce is supposed to be given a *pure* function that only relies on its parameters and doesn't mutate any values. You're trying to produce an array, which would either involve creating the array and then mutating it (adding values), or creating copies of the array (via `concat`), like this:

```
const results = incomes.reduce((agg, v) => 
  v.date
    ? agg.concat([v]) 
    : agg.slice(0, -1)
      .concat([{
        ...agg.slice(-1)[0],
        description: `${agg.slice(-1)[0].description}, ${v.description}`}]),
  [])
```

As you can see, there's a lot of duplicative `slice`ing and `concat`ing going on here, which is wasteful from a performance perspective. Perhaps more importantly, it's hard to reason with and hard to debug. I'd probably stick with using a `for` loop that tracks state and `push`es to an array instead.

```
let results = [];

for (let v of incomes) {
  if (v.date) {
    results.push({...v});
  } else {
    results[results.length - 1].description += ", " + v.description;
  }
}
```